# Is Java Metro mandatory for calling WCF?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services

Why would jaxws not enough as Metro is not well known and so would require a new learning curve for the dev team: what benefits do metro add ?

Comment: What? I have no clue what you're asking...

Comment: well some did : I got my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Java Metro mandatory for calling WCF?

No.  Firstly, you can (in theory) implement interoperability yourself, though it is apparently difficult.  Secondly, Microsoft have apparently released Java bindings for WCF interoperability on Codeplex:

Reference:  [Microsoft Releases Java-Friendly Interop Bindings for WCF Services](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/06/microsoft-interop-bindings)

I cannot tell you whether the Metro approach or the MS bindings will be better.

---

And the flipside is that WCF is not mandatory for using Java Metro either

*"Note: Because Metro-based clients and services are interoperable, you can gain the benefits of Metro without using WCF."*

Reference: Metro User Guide: [Chapter 1.3](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch01.html#ahiar)

---

> Why would jaxws not enough

In theory it is.  In practice, it will be less work to use existing bindings (Metro or MS) than to dredge through the specs, etcetera to figure out how to implement the bindings *and make them actually work*.  Of course, the amount of work will depend on how much of WCF you needed to use.  But reinventing the wheel is usually a bad idea ...

Comment: Great thanks for the link I never encountered it when googling.

Comment: It is on the first page when you search for "Java wcf" :-)